# Xamarin Forms Editor LineBreakMode

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The Editor control doesn't have a LineBreakMode property like for example Labels do. I want to accomplish the same behavior as disabled word wrap on NotePad, where the lines don't wrap and a horizontal slider is shown automatically.

**Any ides on how to make the Editor to NOT wrap the lines?**

Label example:

```
<Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
```

The idea is to have multiple lines if the user presses Enter, but if not the line shouldn't wrap.
[image]

Comment: It doesnt have linebreak mode because Editor is meant to be used for multiple lines . You might want to have custom renderer to achieve the behavior you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:**

```
   <ScrollView Orientation="Both">
            <Editor
                x:Name="editor"
                Placeholder="Once upon a time far far away there lived a bear. The bear lived in the woods all on his own." />              
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. What I am trying to achieve, is the same behavior as Notepad when the Wrap text is off. That is, you can still have multiple lines, but the lines won't wrap to the next line. In that case a horizontal slider should be visible so that the user can scroll left and right.

Comment: Still this is not what I am looking for. You only have one line here, what I need is a multi-line control. Check out how notepad does it. I'm trying to replicate the same functionality. You don't need to go through the trouble of implementing something, I can do that by myself, an idea would be just enough. Thanks for everything so far. :)

Comment: According to your description, you wanna a control without wropping text. Use Entry. If you want multi-line, use Editor.

Comment: I can't use Entry, because Entry is only one line, and I can't use the Editor because it wraps the lines. I just added an example to the question for clarity.

Comment: You could use the `AutoSize`. I have updated the reply.

Comment: The AutoSize isn't necessary. All I had to do is wrap it in a ScrollView with Orientation=Both. Thanks for your help. :) If you modify your answer I will accept it.