# Maui Editor element behavior

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I tried to achieve  an Editor that don't wrapping text with no succeed
I want that newline be by pressing enter and not by wrapping text

How I can get that.?

I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">
             
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout 
            Spacing="25" 
            Margin="5" 
            VerticalOptions="Center" >

            <Border Stroke= "Black" StrokeThickness="2" Background="Pink" >
                <Editor HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="380" BackgroundColor="Aqua" />
            </Border>    
            
            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                
            <Label 
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            
            <Label 
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button 
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
 
</ContentPage>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: It seems your question is about the editor? What editor are you using and what have you tried?

Comment: what have you "tried"?  There is no code to show us that you've tried anything

Comment: Have you looked at the document for `editor`; it mentions the complete event and key

Comment: <Editor HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="380" BackgroundColor="Aqua" />

Comment: All I ask is  in the <Editor /> when the text reach the end its wrap to the next line.  And I don't want wrapping. So how I can cancel text wrapping.   Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61207872/xamarin-forms-editor-linebreakmode

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested `ScrollView`.

Xaml:

```
   <ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout 
        Spacing="25" 
        Margin="5" 
        VerticalOptions="Center" >
        
        <Border Stroke= "Black" StrokeThickness="2" Background="Pink" >
            <ScrollView Orientation="Both" HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="380" >
                <Editor BackgroundColor="Aqua" TextChanged="Editor_TextChanged"   />
            </ScrollView> 
          
        </Border>


       .............

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```